# Searching for a bit pattern in an unsigned int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I'm learning C through Kochan's Programming in C. One of the exercises is the following:

> Write a function called `bitpat_search()` that looks for the occurrence of a specified pattern of bits inside an `unsigned int`. The function should take three arguments, and should be called as such:

`bitpat_search (source, pattern, n)`

> The function searches for the integer `source`, starting at the leftmost bit, to see if the rightmost n bits of `pattern` occur in `source`. If the pattern is found, have the function return the number of the bit at which the pattern begins, where the leftmost bit is number 0. If the pattern is not found, then have the function return -1. So, for example, the call

`index = bitpat_search (0xe1f4, 0x5, 3);`

> causes the `bitpat_search()` function to search the number 0xe1f4 (= 1110 0001 1111 0100 binary) for the occurrence of the three-bit pattern 0x5 (= 101 binary). The function returns `11` to indicate that the pattern was found in the `source` beginning with bit number 11.
>
> Make certain that the function makes no assumptions about the size of an `int`.

This is the way I implemented the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bitpat_search(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, int n);
int int_size(void);

int main(void)
{
    printf("%i\n", bitpat_search(0xe1f4, 0x5, 3));

    return 0;
}

int bitpat_search(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, int n)
{
    int size = int_size();
    pattern <<= (size - n);
    unsigned int compare = source;
    
    int bitnum = 0;

    while (compare)
    {
        compare >>= (size - n);
        compare <<= (size - n);

        if (compare & pattern)
        {
            return bitnum;
        }
        else
        {
            source <<= 1;
            bitnum++;
            compare = source;
        }       
    }

    return -1;
}

// Calculates the size of an integer for a particular computer
int int_size(void)
{
    int count = 0;
    unsigned int x = ~0;

    while (x)
    {   
        ++count;
        x >>= 1;
    }

    printf("%i\n", count);

    return count;
}
```

First, I calculate the size of an integer (can't use `sizeof()`). Then, I align the pattern that we are looking for so that it starts from the MSB. I create a temporary variable `compare` and assign it the value of `source` and I also initialize a variable `bitnum` to 0; it will keep track of the position of the bits we are comparing.

Within the loop I shift `compare` to the right and left (adding 0's to the right and left of the bits that will be compared to the bit pattern), then I compare the values: if true, the bit number is returned, otherwise, source is shifted once to the left and then assigned to `compare` (this essentially shifts the position of the bit that we are comparing in `compare` to the right) and `bitnum` is incremented. The loop stops executing if `pattern` wasn't found in `source` and `-1` is returned, as per the instructions.

However, my program's output turns out to be 14, not 11. I followed the program through pencil and paper and didn't understand what went wrong... Help?

Comment: Numbering bits this way is utmostly confusing.

Comment: What computer are you on that `int_size()` isn't equal to `sizeof(int) * 8`?

Comment: The quoted text is a bit confusing, as the expected answer `11` is in binary...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test is incorrect: `(compare & pattern)` merely checks if `compare` and `pattern` have at least one bit in common. You should use a mask and write `if ((compare & mask) == pattern)`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int bitpat_search(unsigned int source, unsigned int pattern, int n) {
    int i, bitcount;
    unsigned int mask = (1U << n) - 1;

    pattern &= mask;   /* mask off the n rightmost bits */

    for (bitcount = 0; (source >> bitcount) != 0; bitcount++)
        continue;

    for (i = 0; i <= bitcount - n; i++) {
        if (((source >> (bitcount - n - i)) & mask) == pattern)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;  /* not found */
}
```

Comment: Why would  `if ((compare & pattern) == pattern)` work? I don't understand.

Comment: @AregSarvazyan: indeed is would only work if all bits in pattern are set.

Comment: Thanks, it works! However, I don't understand why there is a need to create a mask and mask of the n rightmost bits of  `pattern`.

Comment: @AregSarvazyan: the mask is used to extract `n` bits from `source` at position `i`, and to clear all but the rightmost n bits in `pattern` just in case they are not 0 already.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: the updated code works for `pattern == 0` and for `n == 0`.

Comment: @chqrlie: Try `bitpat_search(5, 0, 2)` -- your code returns -1 when it should return 3

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Really? I don't think so: `101` does not contain `00`, so `-1` is returned.

Comment: @chqrlie: `0000000000000101` contains `00` at bit position 3.  There's no 'size' paramter for `source`, so one would assume its the full size of an `unsigned` (probably 32 bits)

Comment: @ChrisDodd: the specification is ambiguous: it does not properly define what is the *leftmost bit*. In my code, I assumed it meant the most significant non zero bit, but it might also mean the most significant bit. In this case, you would have a match at offset `0`.  Numbering bits from the most significant to the least significant is **so confusing**... I suspect this book has other questionable choices.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: looking at the spec again, given the example and the remark *make certain that the function makes no assumptions about the size of an int*, for `bitpat_search(0xe1f4, 0x5, 3);` to evaluate to `11` can only mean 2 things: either `unsigned int` has a size of 16 bits or my numbering convention is assumed, with offsets starting at 0 for the most significant non zero bit. At least with this convention the return value does not depend on the size of `int`